# How to configure webHttp Binding while creating a WCF service in Azure?

Tags: c#, wcf, azure

I am developing a WCF WebRole service in Azure and need to invoke a method that to give employee data in JSON format.But unlike a normal WCF Web Service, I dont know how to configure the "Web.config" for WCF Webrole and my code "Web.config" for normal WCF service is below:

```
<system.serviceModel>
<services>
  <service name="empl.Service1" behaviorConfiguration="empl.Service1Behavior">
    <!-- Service Endpoints -->
    <endpoint  address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="empl.IService1" behaviorConfiguration="web">
      <!-- 
          Upon deployment, the following identity element should be removed or replaced to reflect the 
          identity under which the deployed service runs.  If removed, WCF will infer an appropriate identity 
          automatically.
      -->
      <identity>
        <dns value="localhost"/>
      </identity>
    </endpoint>
    <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"/>
  </service>
</services>
<behaviors>
  <endpointBehaviors>
    <behavior name="web">
      <webHttp/>
    </behavior>
  </endpointBehaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="empl.Service1Behavior">
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
```

And my code "Web.config"for WCF WebRole (Azure)is as follow

```
<system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the value below to false and remove the metadata endpoint above before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /></system.serviceModel>
```

Now I need to get the URI access "http://localhost/Service1.svc/GetId" where it should respond in JSON data. But for me it is showing that "HTTP400 Bad Request". Help me out.

Comment: Where are you calling this from? "localhost" refers to your local, er, host; if you want to call your Azure service you'll need to substitute the hostname you've assigned to it.

Comment: Hi, i am calling this service in Local Host only. And i am using only Compute Emulator and not having Azure Subscription.

Answer (score 0):

The bad request might be that the request being sent is not valid. If your service was not accessible or found it would have been a different Http error code. Try enabling tracing on your service to see the cause for bad request. To enable tracing follow this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025.aspx)